# When does polymorphism occur

Tags: java, polymorphism, runtime, compile-time

Iv'e seen some blogs and tutorials that say it can occur during compile time or run time, but i am doing a practice quiz and this is my choices.

a. compile time
b. run time
c.debug time
d. early binding time
e. none of  the above <--- my choice.

Comment: If that quiz really has exactly that question, and allows for only one answer; maybe consider this quiz to be, well, not helpful? In essence, polymorphism  is a concept that is "visible" all the time; just in different ways.

Comment: I am not sure stack overflow is ment to answer quiz questions... And i will agree with @Jägermeister

Comment: I see now it's not for that, and the quiz was provided by my school if it is not helpful what should I use to practice and why is one answer not helpful?

Comment: You should go through [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/3033445/learn-java/java-101-polymorphism-in-java.html).

Comment: Polymorphism is not an event that occurs. It's a concept that exists all the time. "debug time" is nothing more than "run time" with a different purpose I guess. And "early binding time" is more a less nonsense because it's a concept as well. I guess what the question means is the step during compile time that decides the static types. Based on  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/interview-question/what-is-difference-between-early-binding-late-binding-complie-polymorphism-and-runtime-polymorphism I'd say your answer is: all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be at early binding, since polymorphism is used while coding to assign a reference variable to other variable of a a superclass or interface of itself.